# Another question about the comments; reminders of the "Be Nice" policy

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging, be-nice

General question here.

If we see nastiness in the comments section, should we drop in a reminder of the "be nice" policy (not directed to a particular user) or just flag for a mod without comment?

Answer (score 4):

> If we see nastiness in the comments section, should we drop in a reminder of the "be nice" policy (not directed to a particular user) or just flag for a mod without comment?

I'd say we do **both**.

Besides flagging accordingly, I think that placing a comment politely reminding about our Be Nice policy and to keep comments for what they are helps dissuade other users from "joining the brawl".

I also sometimes kindly point them to chat, as to encourage discussion *there*. It has proven to me that after including such comment the nastiness stops or at least is cut down.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.

Comment: @DonThermidor_LobsterMobster yes, we should never stop trying to teach/remind users on the proper way of interacting on TWP and the SE network.